# Adaboost in R: Predict for data that does not have dependent variable

Tags: r, boost, predict, adaboost

I tried to use boosting in R from adabag package.

```
library(adabag)  
model = boosting(survived ~ ., data=train, boos=TRUE, mfinal=20)  

# Now I tried to predict using the model for test dataset like this:  
pred = predict(model,test[-1],type = "prob")  
# IT gave me the following error
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(newdata, , as.character(object$formula[[2]])) : 
>     undefined columns selected

```
# But if i give:
pred = predict(model,test,type = "prob")
```

> It predicts and we can get probabilities, confusion etc.

Is there any way, I can predict for the test data which does not have dependent variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can resolve this error is - By injecting dummy values manually.

For Example:

```
test$Y = as.factor(round(runif(nrow(test))))
```

This should help the model understand whenever the test data doesn't have the Output variable.